# How can I run Matlab's Kalman Filter (DSP Toolbox) in prediction-only mode?

Tags: matlab, kalman-filter

Documentation and examples on the `dsp.KalmanFilter` is really scarce. I want to run the Kalman filter in prediction-only mode, where I pass just the control vector as input and no corrections. Can't seem to find a way to do that since the `step` function takes 2 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Prediction step is just multiplying the current state by the model matrix.
Why no do it yourself?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the inner workings of the Kalman filter. I just know how to use it as a blackbox. Care to add an example to help me understand better?

Comment: So it seems like a MATLAB question not a DSP question.